# Why does UNION fail here?

Tags: mysql, join, temporary-tables, union

I have a problem that I can't seem to figure out how to fix.

What I want to do is simple, select data and append a row of sums as the last row. But I keep getting the error

```
An error occurred in SQL1.sql.

Additional information: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the
right syntax to use near 'UNION

SELECT  '' as `id`,
         '' as `Transaction Date`,
         '' as' at line 1
```

**Why doesn't it work?**

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1 AS
(   
   SELECT `acc_transactions`.`id`                                    AS 'id', 
       LEFT(acc_transactions.transaction_date, 10)                AS 'Transaction Date', 
       `acc_transactions`.`vouchers_source`                       AS 'Source', 
       `acc_vouchers`.`name`                                      AS 'Transaction Type', 
       `acc_transactions`.`vouchers_code`                         AS 'Transaction Code', 
       `acc_transactions`.`user_ref`                              AS 'User Ref.' ,
       `acc_accounts`.`user_account_number`                       AS 'number', 
       `acc_accounts`.`name`, 
       `acc_account_transactions`.`note`, 
       CASE 
         WHEN ( CASE 
                  WHEN acc_costcenters_transactions.debit IS NULL THEN 
                  acc_account_transactions.debit_balance 
                  ELSE acc_account_transactions.debit_balance 
                end ) = '0.00' THEN '' 
         ELSE ( CASE 
                  WHEN acc_costcenters_transactions.debit IS NULL THEN 
                  acc_account_transactions.debit_balance 
                  ELSE acc_account_transactions.debit_balance 
                end ) 
       end                                                        AS  'debit_amount', 
       CASE 
         WHEN ( CASE 
                  WHEN acc_costcenters_transactions.credit IS NULL THEN 
                  acc_account_transactions.credit_balance 
                  ELSE acc_account_transactions.credit_balance 
                end ) = '0.00' THEN '' 
         ELSE ( CASE 
                  WHEN acc_costcenters_transactions.credit IS NULL THEN 
                  acc_account_transactions.credit_balance 
                  ELSE acc_account_transactions.credit_balance 
                end ) 
       end                                                        AS  'credit_amount', 
       IF(acc_costcenters_transactions.transaction_id IS NULL, '', 
       Json_unquote(Json_extract(acc_cost_centers.name, '$.ar'))) AS 'Cost Center', 
       `users`.`name`                                             AS 'User' 
FROM   `acc_transactions` 
       INNER JOIN `acc_vouchers` 
               ON `acc_transactions`.`vouchers_code` = `acc_vouchers`.`id` 
       INNER JOIN `acc_account_transactions` 
               ON `acc_transactions`.`id` = 
                  `acc_account_transactions`.`transaction_id` 
       INNER JOIN `acc_accounts` 
               ON `acc_account_transactions`.`account_no` = `acc_accounts`.`id` 
       INNER JOIN `users` 
               ON `acc_transactions`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
       LEFT JOIN `acc_costcenters_transactions` 
              ON `acc_accounts`.`id` = 
                 `acc_costcenters_transactions`.`account_no` 
       LEFT JOIN `acc_cost_centers` 
              ON `acc_cost_centers`.`id` = 
                 `acc_costcenters_transactions`.`costcenter_id`      

ORDER  BY `acc_transactions`.`id` DESC, `acc_transactions`.`id` DESC 
);






SELECT  `id`,
        `Transaction Date`,
        `Source`,
        `Transaction Type`,
        `Transaction Code`,
        `User Ref.`,
        `number`,
        `name`,
        `note`,
        `debit_amount`,
        `credit_amount`,
        `Cost Center`,
        `User` FROM t1;
UNION

SELECT  '' as `id`,
         '' as `Transaction Date`,
         '' as `Source`,
         '' as `Transaction Type`,
         '' as `Transaction Code`,
         '' as `User Ref.`,
         '' as `number`,
         '' as `name`,
         '' as `note`,
         SUM(debit_amount) as `debit_amount`,
         SUM(credit_amount) as `credit_amount`,
         '' as `Cost Center`,
         '' as `User`
FROM t1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1;
```

Thanks

Comment: You ended the first `select` with a semicolon, so in your script `union` is the beginning of the next statement, which is invalid.

Comment: @mustaccio Thanks a lot! please post it as an answer to accept it. I don't know what to say, I had different trials without the comma but seems like I had other errors :/